# Went in our crawl space the other day and noticed one of the posts supporting the main joist of our house is just supporting air

Tags: framing

Not really sure how to describe it, but the main joist running the length of our house is supported by 7 posts and the center post that's right in the middle of our house is completely off-center from the joist. Not supporting it at all.

I am wondering if I can just shove a new post in, not to correct any sinking that has happened, but maybe to prevent any further sinkage?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can see a post sinking down with weight on it, but it usually stops when the weight is removed.  Can add a new longer post or add 1x4s or 2x4 on top of the post(size to fit tight) and just keep checking to see if the sinking stops.

Comment: Yeah I think I'm going to do a whole new post. The current one is so off. I was just concerned I would be causing some damage I wasn't thinking of by wedging one in.

Comment: A support post needs to be a tight fit.  Replacement post are usually 1/8 to 1/4 inch longer than the open measurement from the base/footing to the beam, depending if any sag is in the beam.  An adjustment(sledge) hammer helps to place it.

Comment: Would this have been this way in the original construction? Or did the post get moved when the crawl space was being improved with the plastic vapor barrier?

Comment: We really can't figure out why or how the post has shifted so much. It is attached to a concrete block, and the beam above has notches cut into it like the post originally fit in there.

Comment: Absolutely no reason to put in a whole new post. This is a great post and is attached to its pad already. No doubt it is attached the way it should be and YOU won't know how to do that. Just tap in a pair of wedges or jack the beam up SLIGHTLY and slip in a shim board that is stuck in place when you release the jack.

Comment: Re your comment on the answer.  Is that post plumb?  Is the 4 inch space from sideways movement or tilting?

Comment: I see no indication that that post was ever used to support that jopist,

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/aNKrJAY  I found another picture on my phone (I am not home currently) that shows more. The post I originally put a picture up of is the one further back, not as off center as I remembered. Both posts you can see in this picture are super loose at the bases.

Comment: @IggMonster, I added that pic to your post.

Comment: Looking at closest post, it it seems like it was put into the stirrup on an angle and bolted in place to try to "get under" the beam.

Comment: Is that post embedded in the concrete (?) pad? I suspect that what you're looking at is that the joist has warped sideways, but the angle of that post suggests that it was noticeable during construction.

Comment: The post in the background is not (as) sideways but also looks like it's just barely touching the edge of the beam, if it's under it at all.

Answer (score 5):

I do not believe that the post is sinking. It appears it was never attached.

The pic show the post out of line. If the concrete pads can be shifted, move them to get the posts under the beam.

You can cut some wedges out of PT or Southern Yellow pine and use them to fill the gap between the post and joist.  Then add a [Simpson tie](https://www.fastenersplus.com/products/simpson-ac4-4x-adjustable-post-cap-g90-galvanized?utm_term=&utm_campaign=%23z%20Shopping%20-%20Simpson%20Connectors%20-%20Post%20Caps%20%26%20Bases&utm_source=adwords&utm_medium=ppc&hsa_acc=3477180114&hsa_cam=405501517&hsa_grp=27562935157&hsa_ad=96815346997&hsa_src=g&hsa_tgt=pla-797078167607&hsa_kw=&hsa_mt=&hsa_net=adwords&hsa_ver=3&gclid=Cj0KCQjw_O2lBhCFARIsAB0E8B9xWwxXMI4MWD250ZMurQmkfpU3zkhY3lbqrBQSvQgv-WAq44ZSs6IaAq3LEALw_wcB) on each side to prevent them from "wiggling" out.

If the pads cannot be shifted, the posts look like they can be loosened and new post can be added next to the old to be under the beam. just cut a slight taper on the top edge of the new post to help it get under the beam. I would still use the Simpson ties.

Comment: I should have taken a better picture - the post is like 4 inches to the side of the center beam. It isn't just too short.

Comment: How is the post attached to its pad? Sometines the pads are poured in place and sometimes they are formed elsewhere and placed there, but often they have a square of pressure treated wood in the center acting as a nailing block. The post is nailed to that nailing block in the pad. The existing post may not be pressure treated so it is not supposed to be in direct contact with the concrete.

Comment: Larry Haun explains how the floors were framed on these pier and beam houses. https://youtu.be/yh6cMQnWGwA

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/aNKrJAY    Found another picture that shows more. Slightly off center and very loose at their bases.

Comment: @IggMonster, Good info,  That makes it another issue. Take better pics.  Also move the plastic and take a pic or 2 of the footing, so we know what we are dealing with.

Answer (score 2):

The latest pics show that there is another post which is not supporting the beam or girder. This beam is supporting the floor joists resting on it.

These posts do need to be removed and repositioned under the beam. Assuming if the carriage bolts were removed, the posts would come free of the brackets, then the metal tie down could be used to hold a 1 ft long piece of PT 4x6 or two stacked 1 ft long pieces of PT 4x4 laid down to extend under the beam. One of the pieces would be cut at an angle so that the top would be level. Then position a supporting post on this PT base under the beam to support it. Nail according to code.

Use a bottle jack to slightly raise the beam, measure, then cut the post to the measurement to allow the post to be inserted under the beam. Lower the beam onto the post and nail.

EDIT

It could be that only one 4x4 would need to be laid through the bracket as opposed to two stacked. It should be cut off to level the top where the post rests. You want the post to have full bearing.

Comment: Yep.  If it were me, I would pour some new pads with stirrups in the right position and move the existing posts there.

Comment: Pouring new pads pads is a lot of work. I would use the ones already there even though they are out of line. I wonder how many more pads are out of line? it will be interesting to see if those posts come right off when the bolts are taken out.

Answer (score 2):

Good spotting - We had a lot of sinkage like this after earthquakes in my city in 2011.

One (temporary) solution was called "jack and pack",  a pair of wooden wedges positioned in a Z shape, and then hammered together to support the load above.  Then a pair of nail plates were hammered in either side to hold things in place until a better repair could be decided.   This became a more "permanent" solution as time went on, and insurance companies did their usual process, unfortunately.  Concrete Piles were more common than wooden posts like OP's photo shows.

Now in OP's case this is just about as much work as replacing the wooden bearer post with a single new longer one, however wedging the other posts will help take the load while one is completely replaced.

[image]

**But it's on the wonk**.  In OP's second picture the two metal straps in the concrete do not appear to be under the joist so any replacement post would have to be wider, and would be under some kind of strange sheer loading.

This is not good and could push the joist to the right taking the floor with it.

Instead the fix might be to drill two new holes in the concrete footing and concrete-epoxy in some new straps(red), and then fit a new post vertically (yellow)

Downside is now the footing is taking load off-center.   This means the footing could move to the left.  Fix this by either extending the footing with fresh concrete (green) tied into the existing footing using epoxy and rebar, or remove the footing completely and replace with one in the right place.

Of course this is hard, horrible, cramped work and the costs for someone else to do it will reflect that.

The rear post in the second photo looks about as bad for misalignment and likely needs the same fixes.  Posts behind the camera might do as well.

---

Another solution might be to sister up a new joist  to the left of the existing one, and use jacks to lift the old one while drilling and carriage-bolting the new joist on.

Problem there is that this is under-floor so getting a many-metres long piece of lumber down there could be hard.   A sistered joist may not be able to rest on the ring foundation either so all weight would be through the carriage bolts.

---

As always, don't take structural advise from internet randoms.  You really need a structural engineer to tell you what is appropriate for your area, and will conform to local building codes.  These are presented as ideas, and commiserations for finding such a mistake.

On the plus side, you found it before it causes other damage higher in the house.